# Hidding all table that are inside a Div , but only keep one table that comes just before an inner Div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am working on a web application, and i have a couple of tables that are inside a main Div with ID = `ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView`. now the main Div have many inner tables and one inner Div. so i need to do the following:-

- hide all the inner tables, except the table that comes just before the inner div with id  = `tl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeViewn10Nodes`.

Here is the markup observed using firefox bug :-

[image]

now i have accomplished what i need by doing the following :-

```
#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView > table:not(:nth-child(11)) {
    display: none;
}
```

but this is not very elegant , because if i re-order the folders or add a new folder i need to chnage the `nth-child(11)`. while defining it to hide all the tables except the one that comes before the inner div is more reliable ...
Can anyone advice on this? i am using jquery 1.10.2

Comment: Can i answer this problem using jquery?

Comment: yes you can using jquery !!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var wrapper = $('#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView'),
    tables = wrapper.children('table');

tables.not(wrapper.children('div').prev()).hide()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView">
    <table><tr><td>hide</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>hide</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>hide</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>hide</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>show</td></tr></table>
    <div id="tl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeViewn10Nodes"></div>
    <table><tr><td>hide</td></tr></table>
    <table><tr><td>hide</td></tr></table>
</div>
```

try this:

Answer (score 0):

Use this thing.

```
$("#ctl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeView").nextAll('table').css('display','none');
$("#tl00_PlaceHolderLeftNavBar_ctl02_WebTreeViewn10Nodes").prev('table').css('display','block');
```

Answer (score 0):

Below code is working for you

## inner_div_id:before table {display: none;}